# How to make sonarqube.com work with github

Tags: sonarqube

I have setup a github repo which I want to test with sonarqube. 
I set up a properties file in my repo.

But when I search in sonarqube or want to add my github repo I do not see a option to do that.

My repo is a c# repo.

I look at the online version of sonarqube

Comment: take a look at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild or perhaps https://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/

Comment: Thanks, When I install the server I see nothing after : 1    | 2017.03.10 22:21:23 INFO  app[][startup] Compute Engine startup is on hold. Waiting for Web Server to be operational.   Localhost:9000 does not find a server

Comment: @rWobben the last line of some long is extremely little information for us to help you. And the title of your question is about `sonarqube.com`, but the log file you mention must be from a local installation. Can you please clarify what you're trying to do, and if you're following the linked guides, tell us at which step you're stuck, and describe it more detail.

Comment: oke, I work now from microsoft team services and I have to find out what the connection name and the server-url is. I have looked at my own pages and read the docs but I cannot find it

Comment: I forget to say IM using the online version of sonarqube